# Stepper + String in same Item of a container VAADIN

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a container with some Properties:

```
myMaintenancerateContainer.addContainerProperty(myPerCent1T, FloatStepper.class,null);
```

this adds a stepper with float value in my container.

in fact, I want the stepper + "%", because the value in the stepper is a % value.

I already tried to add +"%" in my item, like this:

```
item.getItemProperty(myPerCent1T).setValue(myPerCent1Stepper+"%");
```

Where myPerCent1Stepper is a stepper field:

```
final FloatStepper myPerCent1Stepper = new FloatStepper();
myPerCent1Stepper.setWidth("50px");
myPerCent1Stepper.setMinValue(0f);
myPerCent1Stepper.setMaxValue(100f);
```

i got an error because Stepper was expected, but received String, because of the +"%".

I looked for a solution on vaadin books, but found nothing to help me in this case.

Comment: did u try adding the percent as a label? `Label p = new Label("%");` and add it as a component after the value

Comment: either add the property as a string or format the myPerCent1T column and add the '%' in the formatting